# Do monster Truck Engines have an ECU/ECM

Tags: engine, electronic-control-module

so I was designing a body for the CRD Monstertruck mod for BeamNG.Drive,
(so I could design the body within the game before making it IRL)
and when considering the engine (I'm coding the JBeam file with the engine torque curve and etc. from scratch) specs, I came across me,

do monster truck engines have an ECU/ECM? or do they run like the old fashioned cars did (if you know what I mean)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about motor vehicle maintenance or repair.

Comment: How is it not related? Its a motor vehicle and the question is about the function of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monster Jam Trucks are currently allowed to use Holley EFI systems. They are computer controlled and tuned. They also have data logging features to aid and enhance engine tuning.

Comment: I watched a show here in the past year (Episode of Faster With Finnegan on Motortrend) where they were working on a monster truck. This truck had a mechanical fuel injection system on it which relied on fuel pressure and orifice size to do the injection, not on an ECU. It seemed very rudimentary, but it worked. I don't remember the exact reason why they were using this method, but it seems that it still exists in the world of Monster Trucks.

Comment: My reference was Holley's Motor Life site dated 06/2021. With video production delays we likely won't see any information in a video series format for several months.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 so, you're saying that even though an ECU is more practical and common, some builds use a mechanical injection method?

Comment: @ZacharyCross - That's exactly what I'm saying. Like I was saying, there's a "reason" why they use the mechanical injection method, I just don't remember off the top of my head. I'll have to re-watch the episode to refresh the noggin'.